# How to run psql.exe with arguments via python script?

Tags: python, postgresql, subprocess

I need to run `psql.exe postgresql://user:pass@host:port/ < backup.sql` command via Python script.
But while script execution, psql.exejust runs without passed arguments includes connection string and file path.

```py
import subprocess
import os

from anywhere import conf

commandlet = os.path.abspath(r"..\psql.exe")
file = os.path.abspath(r"..\348.sql")
user = conf.login
password = conf.password
host = conf.host
port = conf.port
con_str = f"postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/"
restore_str = f"< {file}"


def main():
    subprocess.check_call((commandlet, con_str, restore_str))
    # or
    # subprocess.check_call(f"{commandlet} {con_str} {restore_str}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Command executed via cmd.exe directly: `psql.exe postgresql://user:pass@host:port/ < backup.sql` completed correctly, but via Python script psql.exe just run and waited user input

Comment: The `< backup.sql` should be processed by the shell (`cmd.exe`), not by `psql`. By default, the shell is not involved so you have to add `shell=True` to the `check_call`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher thank you for answer. Solution:
`subprocess.check_call((commandlet, con_str, "<", backup_file), shell=True)`

Answer (score 1):

According to [Michael Butscher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/987358/michael-butscher), solution is:
`subprocess.check_call((commandlet, con_str, "<", backup_file), shell=True)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).